# Como Rotacionar ViewController Manualmente?

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, portrait, landscape, orientation

Iniciei um projeto, onde uso uma CustonNavigationController para controlar a navegação das telas.

Neste projeto, somente uma viewcontroller pode ser rotacionada para o modo landscape. Mas ocorre o seguinte problema, deste modo:

1 - Inicia o app em portrait
2 - Navego até a tela 
3 - Rotaciono o aparelho e a tela entra em modo landscape
4 - Mantendo o app em modo landscape, volto para a tela anterior, o app continua em landscape e não rotacional para portrait.

Em outras palavras: Em CustomNavigationContoller, eu determinei que somente 1 tela poderia ser rotacionada para o modo Landscape. Porém ao retornar a tela anterior é mantido a orientação em modo landscape.

Como poderia rotacionar a tela que está em landscape para para portrait antes que ela seja removida?

Tentei utilizar o código abaixo, mas sem sucesso:

```
-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{

    if (([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft) ||
        ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight)) {

        NSNumber *value = [NSNumber numberWithInt:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];
        [[UIDevice currentDevice] setValue:value forKey:@"orientation"];

    }
}
```

Comment: Galera, foi mais fácil fazer o autolayout do projeto, do que fazer isso :D mas vou manter a pergunta por questões didáticas

Answer (score -1):

Tenta assim.

```
 
#define degreesToRadians(x) (M_PI * x / 180.0)

self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(self.view.transform, degreesToRadians(-90));
```

Comment: Aparentemente o objetivo é modificar a orientação da tela e não rotacionar a view. Rotacionar a view não é uma boa ideia porque push notification, dialogs, e outros componentes semelhantes continuarão na orientação contrária da view rotacionada e a usabilidade ficará comprometida.